# Method addFriend(Person) is undefined for the type ArrayList<Person>

Tags: java

I have 3 java source files.

- `Person.java`
- `FriendsList.java`
- `MyFriends.java`

`FriendsList` contains an array list of objects of type `Person` and a method for adding a new friend to the list.

```java
public class FriendsList{
    ArrayList<Person> friendsList = new ArrayList<Person>(100);
    // Constructor declaration of class
    public FriendsList(ArrayList<Person> friendsList){
            super();
            this.friendsList = friendsList;
    }    
    ...
    public void addFriend(Person friend){
            friendsList.add(friend);
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, in `MyFriends.java` I created a new array list of objects of type `Person`, I declared a new `Person` and I'm trying to add it to the list using the method `addFriend(Person)` but I'm getting an error `"Method addFriend(Person) is undefined for the type ArrayList<Person>"`

```
public class MyFriends{
    public void main(String[] args){
            ArrayList<Person> friendsList = new ArrayList<Person>(100);            
            Person f1 = new Person("Alice", "Anderson", "519-472-4910", "02", "19");
            friendsList.addFriend(f1);
    }
}
```

I tried all other methods defined in `FriendsList.java` but I get the same error message.
I understand that if the source files are in the same folder, the syntax to use a method from the other file is `objectName.method(a)`.

What am I doing wrong?

(Sorry if I'm not asking it right, it's my first question)

Comment: Specifically in your MyFriends class, `friendsList` is not defined anywhere, but the error message clearly shows it's defined as a `ArrayList<Person>`. So we can infer that this is definitely not the full code.

Comment: You have two variables named `friendsList` that have different types, and it's confusing for us and for you.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question to include the definition of `friendsList` in the MyFriends class. I had it in my code though.

Comment: Do you really need a whole class to wrap an ArrayList?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am just following my assignment's instructions. It asked for all these different classes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you want to do the following instead:

```java
public class MyFriends{
    public void main(String[] args){
        FriendsList friendsList = new FriendsList();            
        Person f1 = new Person("Alice", "Anderson", "519-472-4910", "02", "19");
        friendsList.addFriend(f1);
    }
}
```

You were instantiating an `ArrayList<Person>` but what you really want is to create an object of your own `FriendsList` class.

---

It seems that you don't have a no-args constructor in your `FriendsList`, so you need to do the following (instantiating a `List` of `Person`):

```java
public class MyFriends{
    public void main(String[] args){
        FriendsList friendsList = new FriendsList(new ArrayList<Person>(100));            
        Person f1 = new Person("Alice", "Anderson", "519-472-4910", "02", "19");
        friendsList.addFriend(f1);
    }
}
```

Still, in my opinion, you should consider adding a no-args constructor to your `FriendsList` as follows so that my first suggestion would actually work (*thanks @DavidConrad for the hints*):

```java
public class FriendsList{
    ArrayList<Person> friendsList = new ArrayList<Person>(100);
    // Constructor declaration of class
    public FriendsList() {
    }  
    
    public FriendsList(ArrayList<Person> friendsList){
            this.friendsList.addAll(friendsList);
    }    
    ...
    public void addFriend(Person friend){
            friendsList.add(friend);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes sense. Now I am getting a message "Constructor friendsList() is undefined". I have the constructor declaration in FriendsList.java as `public FriendsList(ArrayList<Person> friendsList){  super();  this.friendsList = friendsList; }`
I tried adding `ArrayList<Person> friendsList` in the parantheses `FriendsList friendsList = new FriendsList(ArrayList<Person> friendsList);`

Comment: @cruelladevil, I think you accepted the wrong answer ;). I made a mistake and edited the other person answer instead of mine.

Comment: I hope I got it right this time. I'm still getting used to the site

Comment: Thanks! It was my mistake, I was editing the other answer not mine :D

Comment: @cruelladevil Now eliminate the `super();` call from the constructor (Java will do that by default), and I would suggest not simply accepting a list passed in from elsewhere; the caller could retain a copy and mutate it 'behind your back.' Instead, use `this.friendsList.addAll(friendsList);` to copy them from the provided list into yours.

Comment: Sorry, @JoãoDias, the above comments are for the asker. I know you copied that code from the question.

Comment: No worries @DavidConrad ;) Those are good hints indeed and I will adjust them to help OP and others as well.

Answer (score 2):

You are not actually using the `FriendsList` class.  MyFriends should be:

```
public class MyFriends{
    public void main(String[] args){
            FriendsList friendsList = new FriendsList();            
            Person f1 = new Person("Alice", "Anderson", "519-472-4910", "02", "19");
            friendsList.addFriend(f1);
    }
}
```

Comment: That was it! I needed this line `FriendsList friendsList = new FriendsList(new ArrayList<Person>(100));`
Thank you very much! I would've been stuck at this googling for hours